# Why Elastic search is returning wrong relevance score?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I am learning elastic search, I inserted the following data in the *megacorp* index having the type *employee*:

```
{
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 2,
    "max_score" : 0.6931472,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "megacorp",
        "_type" : "employee",
        "_id" : "2",
        "_score" : 0.6931472,
        "_source" : {
          "first_name" : "Jane",
          "last_name" : "Smith",
          "age" : 32,
          "about" : "I like to collect rock albums",
          "interests" : [
            "music"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "megacorp",
        "_type" : "employee",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : 0.2876821,
        "_source" : {
          "first_name" : "John",
          "last_name" : "Smith",
          "age" : 25,
          "about" : "I love to go rock climbing",
          "interests" : [
            "sports",
            "music"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Then I ran the following request:

```
GET /megacorp/employee/_search
{
    "query" : {
        "match" : {
            "about" : "rock climbing"
        }
    }
}
```

However the result I got is as follows:

```
{
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 2,
    "max_score" : 0.6682933,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "megacorp",
        "_type" : "employee",
        "_id" : "2",
        "_score" : 0.6682933,
        "_source" : {
          "first_name" : "Jane",
          "last_name" : "Smith",
          "age" : 32,
          "about" : "I like to collect rock albums",
          "interests" : [
            "music"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "megacorp",
        "_type" : "employee",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : 0.5753642,
        "_source" : {
          "first_name" : "John",
          "last_name" : "Smith",
          "age" : 25,
          "about" : "I love to go rock climbing",
          "interests" : [
            "sports",
            "music"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I have the doubt that relevance score for the following record:

```
{
        "_index" : "megacorp",
        "_type" : "employee",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : 0.5753642,
        "_source" : {
          "first_name" : "John",
          "last_name" : "Smith",
          "age" : 25,
          "about" : "I love to go rock climbing",
          "interests" : [
            "sports",
            "music"
          ]
        }
      }
```

is lesser than the previous one. I ran the query with

> explain: true

and got the following result:

```
        {
  "took" : 4,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 2,
    "max_score" : 0.6682933,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_shard" : "[megacorp][2]",
        "_node" : "pGtCz_FvSTmteJwQKvn_lg",
        "_index" : "megacorp",
        "_type" : "employee",
        "_id" : "2",
        "_score" : 0.6682933,
        "_source" : {
          "first_name" : "Jane",
          "last_name" : "Smith",
          "age" : 32,
          "about" : "I like to collect rock albums",
          "interests" : [
            "music"
          ],
          "fielddata" : true
        },
        "_explanation" : {
          "value" : 0.6682933,
          "description" : "sum of:",
          "details" : [
            {
              "value" : 0.6682933,
              "description" : "weight(about:rock in 0) [PerFieldSimilarity], result of:",
              "details" : [
                {
                  "value" : 0.6682933,
                  "description" : "score(doc=0,freq=1.0 = termFreq=1.0\n), product of:",
                  "details" : [
                    {
                      "value" : 0.6931472,
                      "description" : "idf, computed as log(1 + (docCount - docFreq + 0.5) / (docFreq + 0.5)) from:",
                      "details" : [
                        {
                          "value" : 1.0,
                          "description" : "docFreq",
                          "details" : [ ]
                        },
                        {
                          "value" : 2.0,
                          "description" : "docCount",
                          "details" : [ ]
                        }
                      ]
                    },
                    {
                      "value" : 0.96414346,
                      "description" : "tfNorm, computed as (freq * (k1 + 1)) / (freq + k1 * (1 - b + b * fieldLength / avgFieldLength)) from:",
                      "details" : [
                        {
                          "value" : 1.0,
                          "description" : "termFreq=1.0",
                          "details" : [ ]
                        },
                        {
                          "value" : 1.2,
                          "description" : "parameter k1",
                          "details" : [ ]
                        },
                        {
                          "value" : 0.75,
                          "description" : "parameter b",
                          "details" : [ ]
                        },
                        {
                          "value" : 5.5,
                          "description" : "avgFieldLength",
                          "details" : [ ]
                        },
                        {
                          "value" : 6.0,
                          "description" : "fieldLength",
                          "details" : [ ]
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_shard" : "[megacorp][3]",
        "_node" : "pGtCz_FvSTmteJwQKvn_lg",
        "_index" : "megacorp",
        "_type" : "employee",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : 0.5753642,
        "_source" : {
          "first_name" : "John",
          "last_name" : "Smith",
          "age" : 25,
          "about" : "I love to go rock climbing",
          "interests" : [
            "sports",
            "music"
          ],
          "fielddata" : true
        },
        "_explanation" : {
          "value" : 0.5753642,
          "description" : "sum of:",
          "details" : [
            {
              "value" : 0.2876821,
              "description" : "weight(about:rock in 0) [PerFieldSimilarity], result of:",
              "details" : [
                {
                  "value" : 0.2876821,
                  "description" : "score(doc=0,freq=1.0 = termFreq=1.0\n), product of:",
                  "details" : [
                    {
                      "value" : 0.2876821,
                      "description" : "idf, computed as log(1 + (docCount - docFreq + 0.5) / (docFreq + 0.5)) from:",
                      "details" : [
                        {
                          "value" : 1.0,
                          "description" : "docFreq",
                          "details" : [ ]
                        },
                        {
                          "value" : 1.0,
                          "description" : "docCount",
                          "details" : [ ]
                        }
                      ]
                    },
                    {
                      "value" : 1.0,
                      "description" : "tfNorm, computed as (freq * (k1 + 1)) / (freq + k1 * (1 - b + b * fieldLength / avgFieldLength)) from:",
                      "details" : [
                        {
                          "value" : 1.0,
                          "description" : "termFreq=1.0",
                          "details" : [ ]
                        },
                        {
                          "value" : 1.2,
                          "description" : "parameter k1",
                          "details" : [ ]
                        },
                        {
                          "value" : 0.75,
                          "description" : "parameter b",
                          "details" : [ ]
                        },
                        {
                          "value" : 6.0,
                          "description" : "avgFieldLength",
                          "details" : [ ]
                        },
                        {
                          "value" : 6.0,
                          "description" : "fieldLength",
                          "details" : [ ]
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "value" : 0.2876821,
              "description" : "weight(about:climbing in 0) [PerFieldSimilarity], result of:",
              "details" : [
                {
                  "value" : 0.2876821,
                  "description" : "score(doc=0,freq=1.0 = termFreq=1.0\n), product of:",
                  "details" : [
                    {
                      "value" : 0.2876821,
                      "description" : "idf, computed as log(1 + (docCount - docFreq + 0.5) / (docFreq + 0.5)) from:",
                      "details" : [
                        {
                          "value" : 1.0,
                          "description" : "docFreq",
                          "details" : [ ]
                        },
                        {
                          "value" : 1.0,
                          "description" : "docCount",
                          "details" : [ ]
                        }
                      ]
                    },
                    {
                      "value" : 1.0,
                      "description" : "tfNorm, computed as (freq * (k1 + 1)) / (freq + k1 * (1 - b + b * fieldLength / avgFieldLength)) from:",
                      "details" : [
                        {
                          "value" : 1.0,
                          "description" : "termFreq=1.0",
                          "details" : [ ]
                        },
                        {
                          "value" : 1.2,
                          "description" : "parameter k1",
                          "details" : [ ]
                        },
                        {
                          "value" : 0.75,
                          "description" : "parameter b",
                          "details" : [ ]
                        },
                        {
                          "value" : 6.0,
                          "description" : "avgFieldLength",
                          "details" : [ ]
                        },
                        {
                          "value" : 6.0,
                          "description" : "fieldLength",
                          "details" : [ ]
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Can you please tell me what is the reason behind this?

Comment: could you run the query with "explain": true in the query body and show the result?

Comment: I have updated the question with the response

Comment: As per the question you are querying on `action` field whereas you explain result shows that field `last_name` is being queried. Are you sure you are checking the result for the query you have added in your question.

Comment: Thanks For pointing that out Nishant, I have updated the result. Please see if you can help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer: Relevance in Elasticsearch is not a simple topic :) Details below.

I was trying to reproduce your case...

First I've put the two documents:

```
POST /megacorp/employee/1
{
  "first_name": "John",
  "last_name": "Smith",
  "age": 25,
  "about": "I love to go rock climbing",
  "interests": [
    "sports",
    "music"
  ]
}

POST /megacorp/employee/2
{
  "first_name": "Jane",
  "last_name": "Smith",
  "age": 32,
  "about": "I like to collect rock albums",
  "interests": [
    "music"
  ]
}
```

and later I used your query:

```
GET /megacorp/employee/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "about": "rock climbing"
    }
  }
}
```

My results were totally different:

```
{
  "took": 89,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 2,
    "max_score": 0.5753642,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "megacorp",
        "_type": "employee",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.5753642,
        "_source": {
          "first_name": "John",
          "last_name": "Smith",
          "age": 25,
          "about": "I love to go rock climbing",
          "interests": [
            "sports",
            "music"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "megacorp",
        "_type": "employee",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 0.2876821,
        "_source": {
          "first_name": "Jane",
          "last_name": "Smith",
          "age": 32,
          "about": "I like to collect rock albums",
          "interests": [
            "music"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

As you can see results are in "expected" order. Please note that the `_score` values are totally different than you.

The question is: Why? What happened?

The detailed answer for this situation was described in the [Practical BM25 - Part 1: How Shards Affect Relevance Scoring in Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/blog/practical-bm25-part-1-how-shards-affect-relevance-scoring-in-elasticsearch) article.

Shortly: as you probably could notice Elasticsearch stores documents split among shards. To be faster, by default it uses [`query_then_fetch`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-search-type.html#query-then-fetch) strategy. This means that Elasticsearch first asks for results on every shard and later will fetch the results and present them to the user. Of course the same happens with the score calculation.

As you can see, in our results 5 shards where queried. Elasticsearch is using 5 shards by default if not specified on index creation (can be specified with `number_of_shards` param). That is why our scores are different. Moreover, if you try to do this again yourself there is a big chance that you get different results once again. Everything depends on how the document is distributed among shards. If you set `number_of_shards` to 1 for this index you will be getting the same scores each time.

An additional thing, also mentioned in the [article](https://www.elastic.co/blog/practical-bm25-part-1-how-shards-affect-relevance-scoring-in-elasticsearch) is:

> People start loading just a few documents into their index and ask
>   “why does document A have a higher/lower score than document B” and
>   sometimes the answer is that the user has a relatively high ratio of
>   shards to documents so that the scores are skewed across different
>   shards.

Elasticsearch was designed to maintain a large amount of data and the more data you put into an index, the more accurate the results you get.

I hope my answer explains your doubts.

Comment: Thank you so much. I understood every bit of it